# Calculate the Height of a Vbox in the Preamble

Tags: fancyhdr

I am trying to calculate the height of a `\vbox` before `\begin{document}`. The goal is to set the header height in fancyhdr, using `\setlength{\headheight}{(insert calculated height here)}`.

This is what I have so far:

```latex
    \newdimen\height
    \setbox0=\vbox{\MakeHeader}

    \setlength{\headheight}{\height pt}
```

where `\MakeHeader` is a command that I wrote which builds the header.

(adapted from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939450/get-height-on-a-block-of-latex-output)).

However, I am getting `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}` when I try to run this in the preamble. When I run it after `\begin{document}`, page 2's header size is properly set but the first page's body margin is too small - i.e. the body of my document and the header overlap.

Is there a better approach than what I am trying to do, and if not, is it possible to calculate the size of that "fake" `\vbox` without LaTeX expecting to be inside the document?

Comment: Typesetting in a `\vbox` starts a paragraph, and that triggers the insertion of `\everypar`, which does the error.  You can try `\begingroup
  \everypar{}
  \setbox0=\vbox{\MakeHeader}
  \expandafter
\endgroup\expandafter\headheight\the\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax`, but typesetting things before `\begin{document}` is not really supported

Comment: There's no real need to set content in a `\vbox` to get the height, as the height can be accessed via `\ht0` (for `\setbox0=\hbox{\MakeHeader}`).

Comment: Setting any text in the preamble is unreliable as fonts are only fully set up at `\begin{document}` Normally the height of the header can be fixed in advance as part of the document design, why do you need to measure?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I agree that most of the time that is possible. However, I am trying to build a document-generation pipeline, and my title has a variable height depending on its length. In my use-case, I wish to calculate the header height when building the PDF.

Comment: it's still surprising to put a variable sized title in the page head, you can do a certain amount as egreg has shown, but especially if you use math the font setup is not finalised. but hopefully that doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `fancyhdr`, you can do it as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text
\usepackage{showframe} % to show the page blocks

\newcommand{\Makeheader}{\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\lipsum[1][1-5]}}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \settoheight{\headheight}{\Makeheader}%
  \addtolength{\headheight}{4pt}%
}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\Makeheader}

\begin{document}

\the\headheight

\end{document}
```

Try with different fonts and font options.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. +1 for pointing me in the right direction, but it seems that (on my non-minimal document) I'm getting the wrong calculation, for some reason. I'm going to continue to experiment--do you think you understand why the "set to height" command may be underestimating the height of my `\MakeHeader`?

Comment: The solution by @egreg forgets to take the `\headrule` into account, and instead adds an arbitrary `4pt`. His idea is good, but needs therefore some tweaking. I'll give a more complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an update on the answer by @egreg. It takes the `\headrule` into account.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text
\usepackage{showframe} % to show the page blocks

\newcommand{\Makeheader}{\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\lipsum[1][1-5]}}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \settoheight{\headheight}{\vbox{%
      \noindent\Makeheader\strut\vspace{\headruleskip}\headrule}}%
}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\Makeheader}

\begin{document}

\the\headheight

\end{document}
```

Because the `\headrule` is placed vertically, it has to be put in a `\vbox`. The `\noindent` is to avoid an `\overfull hbox` warning.
And `\headruleskip` is a fancyhdr Version 4 feature. If you don't use it, the `\vspace{\headruleskip}` can be left out, but I include it for completeness.

I will reference this solution is the future version of the `fancyhdr` documentation. I am about to revise the documentation about changing `\headheight` and `\footskip`, so this comes timely.

Maybe I will make a command in a future version to do this with the information that `fancyhdr` already has, instead of you having to define a command like `\Makeheader`.